# What is the difference between dword and 'the stack' in assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn assembler and am somewhat confused by the method used by osx with nasm macho32 for passing arguments to functions.

I am following the book 'Assembly Language Step By Step' by Jeff Duntemann and using the internet extensively have altered it to run on osx both 32 and 64 bit.

So to begin with the linux version from the book

```
section .data           ; Section containing initialised data
    EatMsg db "Eat at Joe's!",10
    EatLen equ $-EatMsg 
section .bss            ; Section containing uninitialised data
section .text           ; Section containing code
global start            ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

start:
    nop
    mov eax, 4          ; Specify sys_write syscall
    mov ebx, 1          ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov ecx, EatMsg     ; Pass offset of the message
    mov edx, EatLen     ; Pass the length of the message
    int 0x80                ; Make syscall to output the text to stdout

    mov eax, 1          ; Specify Exit syscall
    mov ebx, 0          ; Return a code of zero
    int 0x80                ; Make syscall to terminate the program

    section .data       ; Section containing initialised data
        EatMsg db "Eat at Joe's!", 0x0a
        EatLen equ $-EatMsg 
    section .bss        ; Section containing uninitialised data
    section .text       ; Section containing code
    global start        ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!
```

Then very similarly the 64 bit version for osx, other than changing the register names, replacing int 80H (which I understand is somewhat archaic) and adding 0x2000000 to the values moved to eax (don't understand this in the slightest) there isn't much to alter.

```
section .data           ; Section containing initialised data
    EatMsg db "Eat at Joe's!", 0x0a
    EatLen equ $-EatMsg 
section .bss            ; Section containing uninitialised data
section .text           ; Section containing code
global start            ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

start:
    mov rax, 0x2000004  ; Specify sys_write syscall
    mov rdi, 1          ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov rsi, EatMsg     ; Pass offset of the message
    mov rdx, EatLen     ; Pass the length of the message
    syscall             ; Make syscall to output the text to stdout

    mov rax, 0x2000001  ; Specify Exit syscall
    mov rdi, 0          ; Return a code of zero
    syscall             ; Make syscall to terminate the program
```

The 32 Bit mac version on the other hand is quite different. I can see we are pushing the arguments to the stack dword, so my question is (and sorry for the long preamble) what is the difference between the stack that eax is being pushed to and dword and why do we just use the registers and not the stack in the 64 bit version (and linux)?

```
   section .data        ; Section containing initialised data
    EatMsg db "Eat at Joe's!", 0x0a
    EatLen equ $-EatMsg 
section .bss            ; Section containing uninitialised data
section .text           ; Section containing code
global start            ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

start:
    mov eax, 0x4        ; Specify sys_write syscall
    push dword EatLen   ; Pass the length of the message
    push dword EatMsg   ; Pass offset of the message
    push dword 1        ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    push eax
    int 0x80            ; Make syscall to output the text to stdout
    add esp, 16         ; Move back the stack pointer

    mov eax, 0x1        ; Specify Exit syscall
    push dword 0        ; Return a code of zero
    push eax
    int 0x80            ; Make syscall to terminate the program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't quite understand what is `dword`. Speaking HLL, it is not a variable, but rather a type. So `push doword 1` means that you pushes a double word constant `1` into the stack. There only ONE stack, and both the one and the register eax are pushed in it.

The registers are used in linux because they are much faster, especially on old processors. Linux ABI (which is, as far as i know, a descent of System V ABI) was developed quite a long time ago and often used in systems where performance was critical, when the difference was very significant. OSX intel abi is much younger, afaik, and simplicity of using stack where more important in desktop OSX than the negligible slowdown. In 64-bit processors, more registers where added and hence the where more efficient to use them.